# How to tell ng build to include more files

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to build my application, but the `ng build` command doesn't include all files, like `styles.css` or images or libraries like `c3.js` or `d3.js`.

I can do this by copying and pasting those files into the `dist` folder (where the files go after the `ng build` command), but this is inefficient, because I have to do it everytime I make `ng build`.

How can I make `ng build` automatically include the styles, images and libraries.

**Edit**
`angular-cli.json` file:

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.20-4",
    "name": "scada-lts-ui"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
        "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

The following errors appears, because `ng build` doesnt copy these files from app directory.

[image]

Comment: Please give more information. How have you added these additional assets to your project? How is it structured? What does your `angular-cli.json` look like?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's done, my friend.

Comment: That's only part of what I asked for, but it's already clear that you're only including one library in `scripts`. What about the others? Have you put those images in the assets directory? Where is your root styles.css? Are you using Angular 2 wrappers for any of your dependencies? Have you considered loading them from a CDN if you're putting them straight into the HTML? Etc.

Comment: `styles.css` are inside the same folder as the `index.html` is, thats why it's even stranger that it doesnt copy both of them, but only index... I didn't put these images into assets directory. Im using angular-cli. I will try to load libraries from CDN.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me why it's trying to load `styles.css` at all. Have you added that manually somewhere? The only files I see when I `ng build` my projects are an `index.html` and three bundled JavaScript files (`inline`, `main.bundle` and `styles.bundle`, plus a `.map` for each) - you shouldn't actually have to explicitly load *any* CSS files.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thats quite right, but... when I don't add manually `styles.css` and libraries into the `dist` folder, the site looks like there's a lack of styles, it's not like totally without css, but something is just not right. And if I dont drop these libraries there, e.g. `c3.js` - the chart appears, but looks weird, like styles got mad.

Comment: I'd suggest you do some more research on including third-party modules in Angular 2 projects - it may be easier to use existing wrappers for them, which expose the code you need as modules to be bundled in. As for the issue with `styles.css`, please give a [mcve] - *"something is just not right"* isn't a useful problem description.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok. You can delete your down vote then

Comment: If I had downvoted, why would I undo it? You still haven't actually provided an answerable question; you aren't showing a [mcve] that would allow someone to figure out what exactly you've done wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your files to the "assets"-array in angular-cli.json
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#project-assets

This will include the assets-folder (as is) and the favicon.ico -file

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "favicon.ico"
]
```

If you want the js and css-files to be bundeled in the build

Then add the needed script files to apps[0].scripts:

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
],
```

Finally add the Bootstrap CSS to the apps[0].styles array:

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "styles.css"
],
```

Bundled files are automatically linked from index.html on build,
files and folders included by the assets-array you need to provide links to in your code.

Look at this part of the readme
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation

Comment: Try to add as much as information in the answer itself rather referring links. This is because content of a link can be changed or link can be broken after some time.